# Давайте расскажем о целях и ценностях сообщества коллегам с помощью баннеров

Tags: обсуждение

Хотим ли мы видеть больше увлекательных ответов? — Конечно! Хотим ли мы видеть больше интересных вопросов?  — Однозначно! Почему бы тогда нам не пригласить коллег, которые будут задавать интересные  вопросы и делиться с нами новыми подходами к решению задач?

Один из способов привлечения коллег в сообщество — рассказать им о [целях](/help/manifesto) и [ключевых принципах](/help/key-values) сообщества. Для этого, как мне кажется, было бы здорово сделать баннеры и разместить их на Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на русском.

> Пожалуйста, расскажите:
>
> 1. Как бы вы хотели, чтобы выглядели баннеры, которые будут вести на страницу «[манифеста](/help/manifesto)» и «[ключевых ценностей](/help/key-values)»?
> 2. Какие слоганы вы бы использовали на этих баннерах?
> 3. Какое изображение вы бы рекомендовали добавить?

Пожалуйста, поделитесь с сообществом своими идеями! На основе ваших предложений мы подготовим баннеры, которые будут показываться миллионам русскоязычных разработчиков.

Comment: Я, если честно, не совсем понимаю, какая связь между желанием делиться знаниями и манифестом. Если человек хочет делиться, манифест ему не нужен для этого, если не хочет, то манифест вряд ли поможет в этом =/

Comment: @Suvitruf Как мне кажется, в проектах вроде Stack Overflow (или той же Википедии) ответ на вопрос «почему» / «зачем» (манифест) играет важнейшую роль, кроме того ключевые ценности нашего сообщества сильно отличаются от других сообществ. Например, в личном общении многие упоминают, что не задают вопросы на сайтах, опасаясь грубости. Эти две страницы справки очень важны.

Comment: @Suvitruf В любом случае, это предположение, проверить которое можно только попробовав =) Пожалуйста, предложите ваш вариант баннера!

Comment: Чувствую, что получится что-то унылое и не смешное.

Comment: @РашенБеар У вас есть отличная возможность не допустить этого: пожалуйста, предложите ваш вариант!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky пока я вижу только 2 ответа, и в них шуточные плакаты. Наверное это потому что идея выглядит немного странной)

Answer (score 13):

Если честно, тоже не совсем понял зачем это нужно, имхо одним из достоинств сообщества является то, что адекватный человек может в нем участвовать не проникаясь философией.

Также не совсем понял почему нужна агитпропаганда именно в виде баннеров, но надо так надо. В графике не силен, не судите строго.

Первый:

[image: Манифест]

Второй:

[image: Ключевые ценности]

Comment: > *адекватный человек может в нем участвовать не проникаясь философией*  
Какая прекрасная формулировка. Без сарказма

Comment: а мне не нравится

Comment: @michael_best в последнее время люди здесь минусуют без комментариев, т.ч. спасибо за открытость :) плакаты я нарисовал китчевые, т.ч. критика уместна.

Comment: мне не нравиться тематика СССР, в последнее время это уже (для меня) не выглядит смешно

Comment: @michael_best ок, понятно, не только Вам

Comment: @michael_best а мне наоборот нравится. Как раз из-за советской тематики понянтно, что это шутка. Кстати, очень неплохо

Answer (score 2):

[image: .]